Pygame error: video system not initialized; what does this mean and how do I fix it?
Creating a maze game, with the main game code and player classes being implemented first. Please note that the two are in separate Python files. I am using Thonny. The code is as follows:
MAIN CODE
#import modules
import pygame
import random
from player import Player
from time import sleep
pygame.init()
#set dimensions of game window: 800x600px 
SCREEN_WIDTH=800
SCREEN_HEIGHT=600
#creates screen with dimensions
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#set main game window title
pygame.display.set_caption('Game Window')
#creates colours using RGB values for easy access
white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
#create clock object to control frame rate
FPS=60
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

player=Player(3,0,0,0,0,5,"idle",100,10)
#player_group=pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
#player_group.add(player)

#game loop
running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #exit game
        if event.type==pygame.quit():
            running=False
    pygame.display.update()
    player.update()
    player.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill(white)
screen.fill(black)
pygame.quit()

PLAYER CLASS:
import pygame
from time import sleep
#pygame.init()
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,Lives,startPositionX,startPositionY,X,Y,velocity,state,meter,freq):
        #super.__init__()
        self.Lives=Lives
        self.startPositionX=startPositionX
        self.startPositionY=startPositionY
        self.image=pygame.image.load("sonicthehedgehog.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect(center=(0,0))
        self.X=X
        self.Y=Y
        self.velocity=velocity
        self.state=state
        self.meter=meter
        self.freq=freq
#fillMeter() goes here
#mainAnimate() goes here
#animateAttack() goes here
#animateDeath() goes here
#animateWin() goes here
    def update(self):
        #self.fillMeter(1)
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.X-=self.velocity
            state="left"
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.X+=self.velocity
            state="right"
        elif keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.Y+=self.velocity
            state="up"
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.Y-=self.velocity
            state="down"
        elif keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            state="firing"
        #shoot projectiles when the space key is pressed
        self.rect.clamp_ip(pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect())

When I attempt to run the program, I get "pygame.error: video system not initialized", with the source of the error being line 34 in the main code "pygame.display.update()". When this is commented out, the same error is given, with the source being line 25 in the player class; the main code links to the player class via line 35; "player.update()"
I found that users with similar problems generally did not type the pygame.init() command, although this cannot be the case (line 6 in main code). Furthermore, another frequent issue was incorrect indentation

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [mre]. Good SO questions help to create a library of programming information, which is really only possible if your code sample is succinct. Please also provide a full error message and traceback, for similar reasons. Once you're ready to make changes, please do so in an [edit].
